# Efficient sort of dictionary by keys (integers) returning sorted list of values

Tags: python, performance, sorting, dictionary

Let's say I have the following dictionary structure:

```
dict = { 234 : objRefX, 123 : objRefY, 567 : objRefZ, ... }
```

The keys are ints, values are object references.

Without sorting the dictionary, the most efficient way to return a list of dictionary values in my knowledge is:

```
def toList():
   return list(dict.values())
```

Now, I'd like to sort my dictionary by key and would like to return a sorted list of values (sorted by key). Is there a more efficient way to do it like:

```
def toSortedList(sort_reversed=False):
   list = []
   for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), reverse=sort_reversed):
      list.append(v)
   return list
```

I look forward to your input!

Comment: `sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=sort_reversed)` should be slightly faster as `sorted` will only use the keys to sort. For the rest this is the way to go. As a side note, don't use `dict` or `list` for variable names, since it masks the *built-in* names

Comment: Great, thx for your aswer! Don't worry, I just used the name 'list' & 'dict', as I stripped my code to the bare minimum and for readability issues. What I wonder: If you are inside a class method, e.g. something like def myClassMethod(self): and are using a 'limited' number of lines of code in this method, like in this sort method. Can you really run into big issues using the temporary List name 'list'?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the keys, then get their values.

```
def toSortedList(sort_reversed=False):
    return list(map(dict.get, sorted(dict, reverse=sort_reversed)))
```

About 2.5 times faster than yours for a test dict I made up.

Comment: So this would make it the following one liner, when using the names from above, correct?
def toSortedList(sort_reversed=False):
   return list(map(dict.get, sorted(dict.keys(), reverse=sort_reversed)))

Comment: @darksaga Yes, though you don't need the `.keys()`.